# Processing cursor from PostgreSQL with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to execute an sql function using SimpleJdbcCall and BeanPropertyRowMapper classes but can not obtain a proper List of objects. Looks like there is a pair key-value in the list. Also I have an error:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'com.example.demo.model.MyCalendarDto' to 'org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap'
```

Need to be mentioned that I'm obligated to use this exactly function and can't change it. I use PostgreSql 13. Can someone show me the error?

1. The table:

```
-- cntr_m2.calendar definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE cntr_m2.calendar;

CREATE TABLE cntr_m2.calendar (
    id_calendar int4 NOT NULL,
    period_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    calendar_date date NULL,
    calendar_level int4 NOT NULL,
    calendar_level_name varchar NULL,
    year_number int4 NULL,
    month_number int4 NULL
);


-- cntr_m2.calendar foreign keys
```

2. The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cntr_m2.f_get_year(p_id_year_in integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
 RETURNS refcursor
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    ref refcursor;
begin
    open ref for
    select c.id_calendar as id_year,
           c.year_number
      from cntr_m2.calendar c
     where c.id_calendar = coalesce(p_id_year_in, c.id_calendar)
       and c.calendar_level_name = 'year';

    return ref;
end;

$function$
;
```

3. The entity class:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MyCalendarDto {

    private Integer idYear;
    private Integer yearNumber;

    public MyCalendarDto() {
    }

    public Integer getIdYear() {
        return idYear;
    }

    public void setIdYear(Integer idYear) {
        this.idYear = idYear;
    }

    public Integer getYearNumber() {
        return yearNumber;
    }

    public void setYearNumber(Integer yearNumber) {
        this.yearNumber = yearNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyCalendarDto that = (MyCalendarDto) o;
        return Objects.equals(idYear, that.idYear) && Objects.equals(yearNumber, that.yearNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(idYear, yearNumber);
    }

}
```

4. The repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.MyCalendarDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.*;

@Repository
public class JdbcMyCalendarRepository implements MyCalendarRepository{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct(){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withSchemaName("cntr_m2")
                .withProcedureName("f_get_year")
                .returningResultSet("#result-set-1", 
                        BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyCalendarDto.class));
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyCalendarDto> findMyCalendars(Integer id) {
        SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("p_id_year_in", id);

        Map out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameters);

        if (out == null){
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return  (List) out.get("#result-set-1");

    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning a result with a fixed number of columns. Why not make that a set-returning function and using `select * from f_get_year()` instead? Then you are "just" running a SELECT in Spring JDBC

Comment: I have to follow rules and utiize the functions that alredy exist.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way for Spring to guess the mapping between your procedure columns and your POJO attributes, except if their names are 100% identical, so you have to explicitly tell it how to perform the mapping between then using a RowMapper<Your_POJO>

Here you can find an example on how to do that. (see 1.1 Custom RowMapper)

https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/

Answer (score 0):

It works like this for some reason:

```
@Repository
public class JdbcMyCalendarRepository implements MyCalendarRepository{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct(){
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withSchemaName("cntr_m2")
                .withProcedureName("f_get_year")
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("p_id_year_in", Types.INTEGER))
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .returningResultSet("calendars",
                        BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyCalendarDto.class));
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyCalendarDto> findMyCalendars(Integer id) {


        Map out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_id_year_in", id));
        if (out == null){
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return  (List) out.get("calendars");
    }
}
```